# Function is not defined in expressJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Completely loosing my mind on this:

I have an express app:
here is a snapshot of a few files for this example:
app.js
-models
--Event.js
--Match.js
routes
--matches.js

app.js:

```
global.__base = __dirname + '/';
var MatchModel = require('./models/Match');
var EventModel = require('./models/Event');
//...
```

matches.js:

```
var EventModel = require(__base + 'models/Event');
var MatchModel = require('../models/Match.js')  
router.get('/', [passport.authenticate('bearer', {session: false}), function (req, res) {
    EventModel.something()
}])
```

Event.js:

```
var MatchModel = require(__base + 'models/Match')

function something() {
    MatchModel.createQuery()
    return "jizz"
}

module.exports = {
    createQuery : createQuery,
}
```

Match.js:

```
function createQuery() {
    //..
}

module.exports = {
    createQuery:createQuery
}
```

when the GET matches/ API is called:
Inside Event.js, MatchModel.createQuery() gives the error MatchModel.createQuery() is not a function. but if I move `var MatchModel = require(__base + 'models/Match')` inside the something() function, it works.

Comment: MatchModel is a global variable that is not exported just because it's referenced in the function. You should use a Prototype.

Comment: STOP using globals and your  code won't be so sensitive to loading timing.  Your use of a global like this is a bad pattern and is likely why you have this problem.  It's also possible you have a circular load dependency which also matches the symptoms.

Comment: @jfriend00 could you be more specific. are you referring to my use of MatchModel? could you pleae suggest the right pattern.

Comment: Quite frankly your code is so spaghetti inter-twined that I would relayout the code rather than just  try to make a small fix.  I don't have a small fix suggestion.  For one, I'd make all paths relative and not use a global.

Comment: @jfriend00 I used __base to prevent the hell of ../.../ etc. https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2014/02/20/how-i-work-around-the-require-problem-in-nodejs/

Comment: @Ankan-Zerob - The global is a bad tradeoff just to prevent some `./` because it introduces load order dependencies or potential circular dependencies which are a no-no in clean module design.  And with better code modularity design and disk layout, you shouldn't have to use a lot of `../../` either.

Comment: @jfriend00 appreciate your feedback. please do provide a few links or snapshots as to where I can replicate code structure and correct patters/best practices.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106076/discussion-between-ankan-zerob-and-jfriend00).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a primary function createQuery and define its prototypes as per requirements and then export that function to be used in you `Event.js`

Inside Event.js

```
var matchModel = require(./Match.js)

exports.getSometing = function(){

  var testSomething = new matchModel();

  var resultOfCreateQuery = testSomething.createQuery()

  console.log('Result of createQuery : '+resultOfCreateQuery);
}
```

Inside Match.js

```
function something(){
 //another logic

}

something.prototype.createQuery= function(){
//create query logic
 return "jizz"
}

module.exports = something;
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to require them and append `()`

Event.js:

```
var MatchModel = require(__base + 'models/Match')()

function EventModel () {
    function something() {
        MatchModel.createQuery()
        return "jizz"
    }
}

module.exports = EventModel
```

Match.js:

```
function MatchModel () {
    function createQuery () {
        //Do Something
    }
}

module.exports = MatchModel
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Comment: appreciate your answer. I will convert it in this format. Also is there no requirement to use .prototype?

Comment: You don't need to use it if you put all the variables needed inside the function.

Comment: Uhhh, your match.js does not make `createQuery()` available to the outside world.  I don't understand why you think this would work.  It's private to inside of `MatchModel` only.

Comment: @jfriend00 yup I just ran that and I'm facing that problem :(

Comment: @jfriend00 please tell me what to do :S